# macro to go to specific worksheet when opening closed workbook

Tags: excel

I have a Master workbook with sheets (names of people) that have data that I am copying over to closed workbooks (workbooks are same name as sheets in Master). Each named workbook has 2 sheets (1 named Performance and sheet2 named attendance). When I am on the Master (created multiple macros -macro for each sheet) that when clicked it looks on HDD, finds the name, opens the workbook and copies the data to the sheet. The problem I am having is it copies to the sheet that I was last on and doesn't search for 'attendance' then paste. I know it is something simple I am missing but look to the experts for advise. I am also certain that there is an easier way to do this than create multiple macros and modules but thought I would start with making this version work first.

Here is the code I use that works like a charm except as mentioned it goes to the last sheet I was on when in the workbook.

```
Sub TransposetoJohnSnowScorecard()

Range("E1:K5").Select
Selection.Copy
ChDir "E:\MyTeam\MyName"
Workbooks.Open Filename:="E:\MyTeam\MyName\John Snow.xlsm"
Range("E1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Windows("Working Sample Ledger.xlsm").Activate
Range("A14:AH100").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("John Snow.xlsm").Activate
Range("A14").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

thanks

Comment: Look into setting your books and sheets.

Comment: research how to remove all of those .Select and .Activate lines and as @findwindow said, use set statements.  Often times, .Select statements *rarely* are interacting on the the range you think they are.

Comment: thank you both and big thanks 'findwindow' as you were right and I added the sheet setting and it now works, Now to research and learn to remove the .Select and .Activate to clean the code up and use one macro and not multiple.